# Will running sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev disturb rvm?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, jekyll

I have already installed rvm and few versions of rubies. Here is the list

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.1-p431-dev [ i686 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ i686 ]


# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I tried `sudo gem install jekyll` in all versions but getting the same error again and again

```
sudo gem instal jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

How to proceed with the Jekyll installation.

When reading about Troubleshooting Installation Problem they have mentioned to Install ruby1.9.1-dev package through

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Will it solve my issue without disturbing the rvm?
Please guide me.

Comment: I recommend that you use RVM to install Ruby instead of apt-get. Ruby 1.9.1 has some serious issues with some packages (Rails in particular). It also has poor performance compared with newer rubies or even the older 1.8.7. Ruby doesn't seem to be maintained for apt-get anymore so RVM is the only viable option under Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: But I have installed it using sudo apt-get install. Jekyll works fine and RVM is not disturbed(yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems either the build of [ruby-1.9.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.1) isn't completed, or some of build-in modules for the ruby are absent, for example `mkmf`. So you have to add-in the module into the [ruby-1.9.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.1) installation if any, in order to be able to build native gems with the ruby.

> When reading about Troubleshooting Installation Problem they have mentioned to Install ruby1.9.1-dev package through
>
> sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev

Of course try to install, and then do in [irb](/questions/tagged/irb) of the [ruby-1.9.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.1):

```
require 'mkmf'
```